# Подскажите с unixtime

Tags: python

Мне нужно чтобы код продолжил свою работу в определенное время по unixtime. Я пробовал Переводить время в unixtime в цикле while True, но он постоянно перескакивает нужное время.

```
while True:
    millisecond = datetime.datetime.now()
    t=time.mktime(millisecond.timetuple())*1000
    #print(t)
    if t=='1652032326000':
      print(yeeee)
```

if t=='1652032326000': вот здесь перепрыгивает время

Comment: ту надо поместить минимальный кусок своего кода и указать, где подозреваете ошибку в нем.

Comment: добавил кусок кода

Comment: смотрите всегда на синтаксис функции и тип возвращаемого значения. time.mktime возвращает float, а вы его с чем сравниваете? Исправил код - см. ответ. Проверяйте:-)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать time.time(), но главное просто вместо == поставить >=.

```
import time

need_time = 1652032686 # на 1000 не надо умножать

while 1:
    if time.time() >= need_time:
        do_something()
```

Comment: спасибо) мне интересно узнать можно ли продолжить максимально в точное время

Comment: Точность зависит от скорости выполнения программы. Если нужна максимальная точность можно найти время за которое выполняется одна итерация и отнять его от нужного времени.

Comment: Я не думаю что у вас 1 итерация выполняется больше 1 сек. Если это программа без работы с интернетом и т.п. тем более.

Comment: time.time() возвращает результат типа float. print(time.time()) может дать, например, значение 1652034162.7199974. И даже два последовательно идущих вызова time.time() могут дать разный результат.

Comment: Это на что-либо влияет в данном примере?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно самый простой вариант — это определить, какой длины должна быть пауза и приостановить выполнение скрипта при помощи функции time.sleep. Как-нибудь так (предполагается, что вы захотите продолжить выполнение скрипта 1 января 2023 года, в 0 часов 0 минут по Москве):

```
import time
time_to_continue = 1672520400
current_time = time.time()
if current_time < time_to_continue:
    time.sleep(time_to_continue - current_time)
```

Если исходная задача состоит в том, чтобы приостановить выполнение скрипта на определённое количество секунд, тогда вообще просто `time.sleep(sleep_time_sec)`.

А ждать наступления нужного времени, проверяя текущее время в цикле (если у вас сделано так), это не лучшая идея, потому что тогда процессор нагружается ненужной работой.

Comment: Sleep прерывает выполнение программы, можно не отдавать управление используя проверки времени.

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Наверное вы хотели написать, что приостанавливает, а не прерывает? Если я правильно понял исходную задачу, то это автору вопроса и нужно. Но, если ему необходимо повторять некую операцию раз за разом, пока не наступит указанное время, то да, нужно изменить условие с «==» на «>=» / «<=».

Comment: Да имел в виду приостанавливает. В большинстве случаев нужно что бы программа выполняла что то еще пока ждет.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ваш код. См.комментарий ниже.

```
while True:
    millisecond = datetime.datetime.now()
    t=time.mktime(millisecond.timetuple())*1000
    #print(t)
    # Исправлена ошибка - обе части сравнения приведены к целому
    # И равенство заменено, чтобы не "проскочить" время 
    if int (t) >= 1652032326000:
      print(yeeee)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Ещё чуть улучшил, чтобы не "проскочить", если какая-то системная задача захватит всё, например. Если ответ (мой или других:-) был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). И сообщите, если проблема не ушла.